# How to execute a stop only if it is hit at high volume?

Tags: stocks, online-brokerage, trading-volume

If I want to put in a stop order but have the order executed only if the stop is hit at high volume, do I need to write my own algorithm and execute via a broker API? Or is there a online broker that offers this already?

Comment: Nah, for anything that complicated, you'll have to write something yourself.  It's not hard if a broker has an API like IB, E*Trade, etc.

Comment: ETRADE HAS AN API!?!?! how did I not know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some brokers will have multi-criteria conditional orders where you can select criteria like volume, trading times, movement of other securities or indexes, etc. that need to be met first before your conditional order is triggered. Interactive brokers is one example of such a broker.